# Why will the Unity C# Old Input System work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried for a while now and can not get this code to work:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Debug.Log("Testing");
    }
}
```

I wanted to spawn in a GameObject (which I would have added later) when the player pressed the "E" key on their keyboard.

Comment: How is this not working ? Is this printing so much logs when you press E or not printing any logs at all ?

Comment: Is the script attached to an active GameObject?

Answer (score 1):

If you start the project from the template, the project might have enabled the new Input System. Or you might have enabled it yourself.

In any of the cases, follow these steps:

1. Open **Preferences**: `Edit -> Project Settings`.
2. Navigate to `Player`.
3. Scroll to `Other Settings`.
4. From the Dropdown `Active Input Handling*`, Choose `Both`.

According to the Information you have given, this seems to be the answer. If this doesn't solve your problem, please include some more information.